# Android : issue in read sms from inbox in Samsung Galaxy device

Tags: android, database, sms, galaxy

I want to read SMS from inbox. The code snippet given below works fine on the HTC Desire but does not work on the Samsung Galaxy.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor c= getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null ,null,null);
startManagingCursor(c);        

String[] body = new String[c.getCount()];
String[] number = new String[c.getCount()];

System.out.println("c.getCount() :: " + c.getCount() + "  c.moveToFirst() :: " + c.moveToFirst());

if(c.moveToFirst()) {
        for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++) {
            body[i]= c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
            number[i]=c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
 c.close();
```

On the samsung galaxy `c.getCount()` returns 0 and `c.moveToFirst()`returns false.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code and works fine with android galaxy Tab and galaxy phones.
The values are even displayed in log for your ease of implementation.

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");


            Cursor c = null;
            try {

                String columns[] = new String[] { "person", "address", "body",
                        "date", "status" };
                String sortOrder = "date DESC";
                c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null,
                        null);
                for (int j = 0; j < c.getColumnNames().length; j++) {
                    Log.v("INBOX"," name " + c.getColumnNames()[j].toString());

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: So what's the problem as per your question you would be able to get all details of inbox,, body contains text and address as phone number, there are apart 16 columns that provide different info about that inside it..

Comment: No, i am not able to get any details of inbox like...body text, address...etc. in Samsung Galaxy......but i am able to get all details in HTC desire.

Answer (score -1):

The code is correct. The Problem is samsungs sms-app, which replaces the androids standard app for sms.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).